# Apache POI Cell - getCellStyle and CellStyle - setCellStyle gives different background colour

Tags: java, apache-poi, cell, hssfworkbook

I'm trying to copy a cell style (background color, format, etc) and set that to another cell.

Using this methods:

```java
CellStyle style = originalCell.getCellStyle();
newCell.setCellStyle(style);
```

---

```java
CellStyle cellstyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellstyle.cloneStyleFrom(originalCell.getCellStyle())
```

But somehow the new cell style has different background color then the original one.

[This is how my cell backgrounds looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTvZj.png)

[Thats the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c06Hh.png)

Any suggestion why is that?

Comment: Can you elaborate this *somehow* a bit more in detail? What does [`CellStyle.getFillBackgroundColorColor()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#getFillBackgroundColorColor--) return in the different situations?

Comment: CellStyle.getFillBackgroundColor()  always returns 64, but my original cells has different background colors.

Comment: Why the cloning at all? Your first two command lines set the cell style of `newCell` the same as of `originalCell`. That should be enough.

Comment: Btw.: Excel cell interiors have pattern fills. If cells are filled full color, then there is solid pattern fill where fill **foreground** color is the color of the visible solid pattern. Fill **background** color is the color behind the pattern that is not visible when using solid pattern fill.

Comment: The cloning was just another try of mine, I'm not using both.

Comment: Then I cannot reproduce that issue. `CellStyle style = originalCell.getCellStyle(); newCell.setCellStyle(style);` works for me and sets the cell style of `newCell` the same as of `originalCell`. Please show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).